# Pusher: Difference between channel binding and Laravel echo

Tags: laravel, pusher

I recently worked on a notification system using Pusher and Laravel. unfortunately can't make it work this way:

```
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'WORKING KEY ..',
     cluster : "mt1",
     encrypted: true

 });
```

and

```
window.Echo.channel('post')
    .listen('ArticleEvent', function (e) {

    console.log(e);

});
```

While messages was sent to client console, but `Listen` didn't worked at all... and nothing logged.

anyway I used this way and it worked:

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

var pusher = new Pusher('WORKING KEY ..', {
    encrypted: true,
    cluster: 'mt1',
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('post');

channel.bind('ArticleEvent', function(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e['message']));
});
```

What is deference between 2 ways and which must be preferred?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, define didn't work please

Comment: @CaddyDZ Tnx, I'm not new to here, i've lost my old account... as i mentioned, `Listen` don't work at all. `window.Echo.channel('post')` worked correctly but at `Listen` part, code seems to stopped and nothing passed to `function(e)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include namespace information in the Listen method.

Please try using (note the `.` character):

```
window.Echo.channel('post')
    .listen('.ArticleEvent', function (e) {

    console.log(e);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked.. Do i need to store notifs in database for offline users? (so when they back online can see notifications) .

Comment: Correct, Channels doesn't store any messages and only publishes them to subscribed clients.